# How do I get a multicharacter output from input() function in Python

Tags: python, list, input

When input() is used, the resulting string considers the characters inside uniquely say:-

```
list(input(""))
1,2,3,4,5,78
['1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5', ',', '7', '8']
```

What if I want to get 78 as a result, What should I do?

Comment: It’s using `list()` that’s turning a sequence of characters into a list of each of those characters. Instead of using `list()`, simply don’t then you’ll get whatever string you provided as input. If your string is a comma-separated list, use e.g. `itemstring=input()` and then `items=itemstring.split(“,”)` to get a list of the items between commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.split(',')` to reformat the inputted string into a list of numbers (as strings). Like this:

```
l = input().split(',')
```

**More Detail:**
The input function gets a string from the user, calling split on that string allows us to split the string into a list of values separated by a delimiter (here we used a comma). What you were doing in your original code was splitting the string into a list of individual characters. [Read more on types here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp).

Comment: Please Elaborate

Comment: @DrDexterMorganMD added a little bit of detail

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
input("").split(",")
```

Comment: Why pass an argument to `input`? The default is no prompt